# Apache Flink: Is it possible to implement a window Trigger that depends on multiple keys?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Can I write a custom trigger policy in Flink which makes decision on emitting by looking at a collection of keys instead of just a single key?

Answer (score 1):

No.
Flink's "Trigger" is shared in its own TaskManager. You can't keep any internal state in Triggers, otherwise the side-effect is unknown.
It's already demonstrated in the comments of [Trigger.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/Trigger.java).